# VS 2015 Cannot install Cordova Plugins

Tags: cordova, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-cordova

In VS 2015 Community edition I cannot install community plug-ins via Apache Cordova Tools. I am receiving following error:

> Your environment has been set up for using Node.js 0.12.2 (ia32) and npm.
>   ------ Ensuring correct global installation of package from source package directory: D:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 14.0\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\APACHECORDOVATOOLS\packages\vs-tac
>   ------ Name from source package.json: vs-tac
>   ------ Version from source package.json: 1.0.34
>   ------ Current package installation is corrupted. Will cleanup and do a fresh installation.
>   unbuild vs-tac@1.0.34
>   ------ Installing globally from source package. This could take a few minutes...
>   Each package is licensed to you by its owner. Microsoft is not responsible for, nor does it grant any licenses to, third-party packages. Some packages may include dependencies which are governed by additional licenses. Follow the package source (feed) URL to determine any dependencies.
>   'D:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.
>   ------ npm install failed. Exit code: 1
>   ------ Package installation failed. Retrying...
>   npm WARN uninstall not installed in D:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules: "vs-tac"
>   'D:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.
>   ------ npm install failed. Exit code: 1
>   ------ Package installation failed. Retrying...
>   npm WARN uninstall not installed in D:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules: "vs-tac"
>   Task attempted to log before it was initialized. Message was: Error installing local npm package.
>   Installing plugin 'cordova-plugin-device-orientation'
>   Starting launch process D:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe "D:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\vs-tac\pluginInstall.js" --action install --projectSourceDir "D:\Projects\MyApp\MyAppCordovaApp" --pluginName cordova-plugin-device-orientation --language en-US  --cliVersion 6.0.0 --npmInstallDir "D:\Program Files\nodejs"  --loglevel warn
>   module.js:338
>       throw err;
>             ^
>   Error: Cannot find module 'D:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\vs-tac\pluginInstall.js'
>       at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:336:15)
>       at Function.Module._load (module.js:278:25)
>       at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:501:10)
>       at startup (node.js:129:16)
>       at node.js:814:3
>   Done

When I try to copy vs-tac module manually from \ApacheCordovaTools\Packages folder into D:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules folder, as soon as I hit add plugin button it gets deleted. I think every time it tries to make a clean install.

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Have you tried to install vs-tac with this command?  npm install -g "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\ApacheCordovaTools\packages\vs-tac"

Answer (score 0):

I can't be sure that your node version 0.12.2 is the only issue causing your problem, but the [VS TACO Setup Guide](https://taco.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/ios-guide/) states:

> Install version 0.12.9 of Node.js.
>
> This version of node.js is compatible with all versions of Cordova. If
>   you have trouble finding it on the Node.js website, see Install the
>   most compatible version of Node.js (0.12.x).
>
> That said, you can use Node.js version 4x or 5x as long as your
>   project uses Cordova CLI version 5.4.1 or later.

I hope this helps.

Comment: I updated to Node.js 5.6.0 (x64) and still same issue.

Comment: @Teomanshipahi Have you cleared your cordova cache and run the dependency checker tool?  VS15 Tools > Options > Tools For Apache Cordova > Cordova Tools